# Trouble while updating and installing programs in Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux

I face the following message when I am trying to install programs in Kali Linux.

```
# apt-get install lm-sensors hddtemp sensors-applet computertemp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package computertemp
```

Comment: did you run `apt-get clean` and `apt-get update` before trying to install the packages? maybe your cache is stale.

Comment: Note that Kali is used for [penetration testing](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me): You put it onto an USB stack, walk into a company, and hack their computers. It's not meant for daily use, it's not meant to install packages (often this will not work), and in particular it's not meant to monitor temperatures. Switch to some other Debian-based distribution, and you'll have all the hacking tools Kali has, but none of the trouble (but ofc, you still have to pick the correct package names).

Answer (score 3):

There is no [`computertemp` package](http://pkg.kali.org/search?package_name=computertemp) in Kali Linux (or, for that matter, its parent distribution, Debian), so you can’t install it using `apt-get`.

If you’re using the default GNOME desktop environment, you could install [the Sensory Perception GNOME extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1145/sensory-perception/) instead.